# Why is this delegate variable null?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I want to pass a method in the MainViewModel to a delegate variable in the LoginViewModel object like this:

```
public class ApplicationViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private LoginViewModel loginViewModel;

    public ApplicationViewModel()
    {
        loginViewModel = new LoginViewModel();
        this.loginViewModel.Login += this.checkLoginData; //stays null..
        CurrentPageViewModel = this.loginViewModel; //works fine
    }

    private void checkLoginData(string username, string password)
    {
        //validating data
    }
}
```

But for some reason, the loginViewModel.Login is null...

And this Command in the LoginViewModel keeps firing this at start, and telling me that the Login == null, which is not what I expect because I initialize the delegate at the MainViewModel constructor.

I'm not a expert at MVVM/WPF, but I trying to work for it.

EDIT: extra information.

And loginViewModel.Login is a delegate variable like this:

```
class LoginViewModel : ObservableObject, IPageViewModel
{
    public delegate void DelegateLogin(string username, string password);
    private DelegateLogin _login;

    public DelegateLogin Login 
    {
        get { return this._login; } 
        set
        {
            /*
            if(this._login != value)
            {
                this._login = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Login");
            }*/

            this._login = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Login");
        }
    }

    public ICommand CheckLoginCommand
    {
        get 
        {
            if (Login != null)
            {
                this.checkLoginCommand = new Command(p => { Login(this._username, this._password); });
            }

            else
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Login DELEGATE IS EMPTY!?!?!"); //keeps firing...
            }
            return this.checkLoginCommand; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Login` is delegate or event? Post how that's declared also.

Comment: Additionally, is "checkLoginData" a method, or just another delegate/event variable?

Comment: `Login` cannot be null after you assign it a handler.  Either 1) The sequence isn't as you are claiming, or 2) you've managed to create 2 separate instances of the viewmodel class.  But, you haven't posted enough detail for us to have any insight into those points.

Comment: Login is a delegate and checkLoginData is a method. I've added a bit more code, and I haven't created 2 viewmodel class, it's very simple basic application, it's just a start of my first try of a MVVM program.

Comment: Ok ... but where is this line placed? `this.loginViewModel.Login += this.checkLoginData;`  Is it in the view's code-behind?  The basic structure/flow of your code still isn't clear ...

Comment: What I'm getting at is this:  the line `this.loginViewModel.Login += this.checkLoginData;` is presumably running *after* some XAML binding invokes the `Login` getter.

Comment: Oke now I believe I have given the complete picture of my 2 ViewModels and their fields/properties.

Comment: Yes I do think that's the case... but I don't know how to solve that.. do I have declare something extra? To tell XAML to wait for bind...?

Comment: I posted an answer, but it's really just something to try.  I still suspect there might be another problem -- your code snippets still don't reveal where the `DataContext` is being set for your view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public ICommand CheckLoginCommand
{
    get 
    {
        if (this.checkLoginCommand == null)
            this.checkLoginCommand = new Command(p => {
                if (Login != null)
                    Login(this._username, this._password); 
                else
                    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Login DELEGATE IS EMPTY!?!?!"); //keeps firing...
            });
        return this.checkLoginCommand;
    }
}
```

This has the advantage of creating the command regardless of whether the `Login` delegate set.  Other things aside, hopefully `Login` will be ready by the time the command gets invoked.

Comment: Thanks! This works... but I've seen more of those "hopefully -blablabla- runs before -blablabla-" in WPF/Windows 8 and other XAML platforms... why is that? Isn't there a real execute order?

Comment: @Kil'jaeden haha ... well, there *is* a defined order, but it *can be* subtle, and that subtlety/complexity is fraught with beginner gotchas.  To be fully comfortable with it requires a bit of insight of both C# and the XAML data-binding framework.